# make bootstrap modal popup behave like alert asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to show a modal popup on PageLoad() Event but the problem is when the modal popup shows up, in background the page is loaded already and is not able to stop the loading unlike normal alert

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" runat="server">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="modal-header" runat="server">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <label id="lblMasterMessage"></label>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label id="lblMasterbodyMessage"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModals(message, header, url) {
        $(<%= myModal.ClientID%>).modal('show');
        $('#lblMasterMessage').html(header);
        $('#lblMasterbodyMessage').html(message);
        //alert(message);
        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            if (url != '') {
                window.location = url;
                Console.log("done");
            }
        });
    }
</script>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string message = "Processing Can Only Be Done On Month Last Effective Day!!";
        string header = "Info";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "LaunchServerSide", "openModals('" + message + "','" + header + "','BusinessHomePage.aspx');", true);
    }
}
```